# How do I select the first element in a the table returned by a SQL function

Tags: sql, sql-server

Suppose I have a SQL function that returns a table and I get the table with

```
SELECT * FROM my_function('x','y');
```

Suppose that I want to write a query that returns a scalar value of the first column value in the first row returned by `my_function('x','y').

What is the query to do that?

Comment: What database are you using? What language are you using to get the returned table?

Comment: This is part of a bigger SQL Query on my MS SQL database.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

SQL Server:

```
SELECT TOP 1 * FROM my_function('x','y');
```